# Can you specify multiple router-outlet in angular and route without naming them?

Tags: angular, router

For example, in this project, https://codesandbox.io/s/github/techiediaries/angular-router-demo?file=/src/app/app.component.html,

The feature of multiple routing is working, however when clicking on the `Product Link`, the url redirects from:

> https://ykj78rkr1j.csb.app/products

to

> https://ykj78rkr1j.csb.app/products(sidebar:products)

I want to remove `(sidebar:products)`, Is there any way to create two routers that independently route different components determined by the same url?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  I want to say no; but, I may not have a clear understanding of what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to route 2 router-outlet with the same url. without adding () to the url.

Comment: You are literally specifiying that sidebar appears in the routerLink:

```

Comment: Yes, but as 2 separate routing entities, basically in the example the sidebar  matches its own "products", I want it to match the same url.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Let me post an example for you

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'postLogin', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/postLogin/postLogin.module').then(m => m.PostLoginModule) }
];
```

**postlogin-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PostLoginEntryComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'playbook', loadChildren: () => import('./playbook/playbook.module').then(m => m.PlaybookModule) }
        ],
    },
];
```

**playbook-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PlaybookEntryComponent,
        children: [
            //export pdf
            {
                path: 'exportPdf/:playbookId',
                component: ExportPdfComponent
            },
            //when they click on block or header in tree structure, when they want to go to listview
            {
                path: 'blockView',
                component: BlockViewEntryComponent
            },
            //when they click group by from listview
            {
                path: 'columnView/:type/:columnType/:blockId/:leftSideBarType',
                component: ColumnviewComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'keypointsList',
                component: KeypointsListEntryComponent
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

Here if you check my code correctly my route url are as follows:

1. postLogin/playbook/exportPdf/:playbookId
2. postLogin/playbook/blockView
3. postLogin/playbook/columnView/:type/:columnType/:blockId/:leftSideBarType

**Note**: Dont forget to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` when you add a routing.module file

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's what I was asking for, I was asking more for 2 routing on the same url.

Comment: What he wants is IMPOSSIBLE with routes.  He can accomplish what he wants with an ngSwitchCase  that loads  a different component based on some value passed as data. 

I’m trying not to comment on the architecture but......

Comment: @LJohnson Thank you, that might be what I was looking for, whether this was even a possibility